# Term for realistic fictional documentation, artifacts, tools

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I’m imagining contextual details in a fantasy fiction setting like technical drawings of alien plants, diagrams of demon physiology, guidelines for communicating with inter dimensional beings. I suppose you see it a lot with occult fiction (finding information in dense intricate tomes,performing precise rituals, etc) and in fantasy where the author establishes realism by conceiving of the types of things you might find in a scholar’s library in that setting.

Is there a general term for that type of documentation of a certain lore, mythos, or any body of knowledge (whether or not connoting fictional contents)? “Marginalia” has the spirit of what I’m imagining.

Comment: The word would be the same in the real world as a fictional setting. The generalized term is “the literature”.

Comment: A well-known example of fictional documentation is the *Necronomicon*, which was a fictional grimoire in stories by H. P. Lovecraft and others. Other examples are Isaac Asimov's *Encyclopedia Galactica* and J.R.R. Tolkien's *Red Book*. To refer to something as "*a* Necronomicon" (or similar) would be to describe it as a fictional work of that type.

Comment: *Codex* might work for you.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific: what kind of content in what kind of format. There's a wide range of stuff you might be talking about: fake maps, narratives of imaginary mythology/religion/history, constructed languages,  imaginary scientific explanations (e.g. James Blish's explanation of the spindizzy), 
actual fake documents (books, letters, texts etc) that exist as physical objects, constructed spaces/installations (whether created for photographs, movies, exhibitions, or just to help creation), fake artefacts (of the sort sometimes sold as collectibles), ...

Comment: If 'marginalia' has the spirit of what your imagining then I, for one, fail to understand anything beyond that. Can you rephrase the exposition, if not the Question?

Comment: How is 'marginalia' not both a generic term, equally applicable to every imaginable setting, and also pretty-much the opposite of what you describe? Why would this not be better Asked in Writing or even Worldbuilding?

Comment: @Steve kindly be more specific about your requirements from the word/phrase. Please provide example sentences, fill-in-the blank sentences and research you have done. You have mentioned "Marginalia". What other words have you considered? Have you found other words that were adequate? Have you found other words that were nearly adequate but lacking in some aspects? If so in what aspects were they lacking? As the saying goes "help us in helping you".

Answer (score -1):

Generally "world" or "universe" is suffixed to another word in your case scenario. e.g. "alien-world", "world-of-warcraft", "JRR Tolkien Universe", "MCU(Marvel comic universe)".

I am imagining you are searching for a term which is a general term for these fictional worlds/universes. Supposing XXXX is such a word, and you can say the following sentences

- JRR Tolkien created XXXX
- Marvel franchise created XXXX

A few candidate words are out there

- [Altverse](https://verse-and-dimensions.fandom.com/wiki/Altverse)(Verse and Dimensions Wikia) (Alternate Universe)(Even in a created world universe, it may be an alternate version of the canonical (so to say) version and can be used for both)
- [Converse](https://converse.fandom.com/wiki/Constructed_Universe_Wiki)(Converse Wiki) (Constructed Universe)(It does not help that 1. **converse** is an actual word with a different meaning, 2. **Converse** is a well known apparel, sports brand)(Hyphenated **Con-Verse** may be usable)
- [Conworld or Con-world](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conworld)(Wiktionary) (Constructed World)(Has entered dictionaries)
- [paracosm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paracosm#English)(Wiktionary) (May not serve your purpose)
- *Fiction/al world/universe* are also acceptable.

*[Conlang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conlang)*(Wiktionary) is constructed language, *[conculture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conculture)*(Wiktionary) is constructed culture.

Comment: That's quite logical in itself and don't you think it wholly side-steps the Question? Aren't those examples all specific instances rather than general terms? Aren't they pretty-much individual cases as opposed to generic terms?

Comment: Kindly look at comment by Stuart F to OP. Also look at OP and other comments there. I think my answer is specific enough. For single word requests OP needs to provide an example sentence and explain enough his requirements from the word/phrase and include research done by him/her.

Comment: The point is not that your Answer is specific enough, but that it is purely specific when the Question clearly sought a generic term. I say again, your Answer is logical in itself and I ask again,  don't you think it wholly side-steps the Question? How does that last Comment stop any of your examples being not general terms  but specific instances? individual cases as opposed to anything broadly applicable to many, if not most cases?

Comment: Please be more specific. Why do you think I'm sidestepping the question? According to you what is the question?

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it follows [our Help Center's guidance on how to reference work by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). ***We are not a link farm***, and a bare unattributed link does no one any good. Our reuse licence allows for plain-text reuse, and so the link would be lost if not given in actual text.

Comment: Provided link, name of source and meaning if word/words is not in common use

Comment: @banuyayi Please be specific about your doubts or accept that the point is not whether your Answer is 'specific enough' but simply that your suggestions apply only to specific instances,  while the Question clearly sought a generic term.

I say again, your Answer is logical in itself and I ask again, don't you think specific - necessarily limited - examples side-step the OQ request for a generic solution?

Comment: Why are we displaying unnecessary and excessive excitement? For me, it seems like a confused disturbance far greater than its cause merits. I refuse to engage lest it becomes a cavemen style brawling. I asked OP for more clarification.

Comment: @banuyayi Sorry you make it necessary to be repetitious and since you insists, please state your doubts or accept that the point is not whether your Answer is 'specific enough' but simply that your suggestions apply only to specific instances, while the Question clearly sought a generic term. I say again, your Answer is logical in itself and I ask again, don't you think specific - necessarily limited - examples side-step the request for a generic solution?

If you won't address that issue, can you explain why you believe it to be irrelevant?